# Find sequence IDs of DNA subsequences in DNA-sequences from FASTA-file

Tags: biopython, fasta

I want to make a function that reads a FASTA-file with DNA sequences(possibly ambiguous) and inputs a subsequence that returns all sequence IDs of the sequences that contain the given subsequence.

To make the script more efficient, I tried to use `nt_search` to make give all possibilities of the ambiguous sequence from the FASTA. This seemed more efficient than producing all unambiguous possibilities, especially for larger sequences an FASTA-files.

Right now, I'm struggling to see how I can check whether the subsequence is part of the output given by`nt_search`.

I want to see if eg `'CGC'` (input subsequence) is part of the possibilities given by `nt_search`: `['TA[GATC][AT][GT]GCGGT']` and return all sequence IDs of sequences for which this is true.

What I have so far:

```
def bonus_subsequence(file, unambiguous_sequence):
    seq_records = SeqIO.parse(file,'fasta', alphabet =ambiguous_dna) 
    resultListOfSeqIds = [] 
    print(f'Unambiguous sequence {unambiguous_sequence} could be a subsequence of:')
    for record in seq_records:
        d = Seq.IUPAC.IUPACData.ambiguous_dna_values 
        couldBeSubSequence = False;    
        if unambiguous_sequence in nt_search(unambiguous_sequence,record): 
            couldBeSubSequence = True; 
        if couldBeSubSequence == True:
            print(f'{record.id}')
            resultListOfSeqIds.append({record.id})
```

In a second phase, I want to be able to also use this for ambiguous subsequences, but I'd be more than happy with help on this first question, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood You well but you can try this:

Example fasta file:

```
>seq1
ATGTACGTACGTACNNNNACTG
>seq2
NNNATCGTAGTCANNA
>seq3
NNNNATGNNN
```

Code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import SeqUtils
from Bio.Alphabet.IUPAC import ambiguous_dna

if __name__ == '__main__':

  sub_seq = input('Enter a subsequence: ')
  results = []

  with open('test.fasta', 'r') as fh:
      for seq in SeqIO.parse(fh, 'fasta', alphabet=ambiguous_dna):
        if sub_seq in seq:
          results.append((seq.name))

  print(results, sep='\n')
```

Results (console):

```
Enter a subsequence: ATG
Results:
seq1    
seq3
```

```
Enter a subsequence: NNNA
Results:
seq1    
seq2    
seq3
```